# Grails null identifier error appearing sometimes without explanation

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, tomcat, grails

I have a production app on grails 2.5.6 using postgres and deployed on tomcat 8.  I sometimes have a null identifier exception when trying to save in any entity. 
When i restart tomcat everything is fine.

My problem is the frequency is not know sometimes it's happens sometimes not,
if someone have any idea of this error is it possible to help.

{
2020-03-15 11:24:52,456 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - 
TransientObjectException occurred when processing request: [POST] /secur/pays/save
The given object has a null identifier: com.referentiel.Pays. Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: The given object has a null identifier: com.referentiel.Pays
        at com.referentiel.PaysController.$tt__save(PaysController.groovy:138)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at grails.plugin.multitenant.core.servlet.CurrentTenantServletFilter.doFilter(CurrentTenantServletFilter.java:53)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

}

Comment: Could you add any more information about the errors you are seeing?  It would also help to understand more about the structure and contents of the entities you're saving.

Comment: Add try/catch and log+share the whole stacktrace

Comment: the fact is when it's come the error is not linked to any entity so the same message apear for all classes when i try a save or update but the app is always running and i can see list and other methods